# Token generated not showing in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using the invitation gem where users can invite other users to join an organization. When a invite is created it generated the secure token but when i pass it to the url it doesn't show.

Here is my invite mailer. As you can see im passing in the the token inside the url.

```
def new_user(invite)
    @invite = invite
    @user_registration_url = Invitation.configuration.user_registration_url.call(invite_token: @invite.token)
    mail(
      from: Invitation.configuration.mailer_sender,
      to: @invite.email,
      subject: I18n.t('invitation.invite_mailer.new_user.subject')
    )
  end
```

Here is my invite_mailer/_new.html.erb

```
<p><%= t('invitation.invite_mailer.new_user.hello', email: @invite.email) %></p>

<p><%= raw t('invitation.invite_mailer.new_user.someone_invited_you',
             sender: @invite.sender.email, invitable: @invite.invitable.invitable_name, url: root_url) %></p>

<p><%= @user_registration_url %></p>

<p><%= t('invitation.invite_mailer.new_user.ignore').html_safe %></p>
```

Here is what printed out in the console.

```
["email","test@gmail.com"], ["token", "f40e26e5df7283222aa51c081d6ae0638214c3d7"], ["sender_id", 95], ["invitable_id", 82], ["invitable_type", "Patient"], ["created_at", "2019-01-26 06:20:16.316999"], ["updated_at", "2019-01-26 06:20:16.316999"]]
```

and this is what i get in the email

test@gmail.com has invited you to # at http://localhost:3000/. You can accept the invitation with the url below.

Invitation Config

```
Invitation.configure do |config|
   config.user_model = '::User'
   config.user_registration_url = ->(params) { Rails.application.routes.try(:url_helpers).try(:users_welcome_url,params) }
   config.mailer_sender = 'info@health-e-medrecord.com'
   config.routes = true
   config.case_sensitive_email = true
end
```

Comment: are you sure the controller already provide value for `@user_registration_url`

you can put byebug there and execute the code to make sure

Comment: well i have a invitation.rb in my initializers that provides the user_registration_url. Am i passing @invite.token wrong in the url? By the way i updated my code fo invitation.rb